# jQuery - Change background color of body using conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some divs and by default only one is visible and all others are hidden. Every div has a different background color.
Based on some buttons when are clicked , different divs are displayed.

I need  to check which div is displayed and based on that I want to change the body background  NOT on button click event.

I have some other buttons next/prev that move into divs, and if I change color on button click when I use those buttons the color stay the same for all divs!! For that i want to make an independent function that will check when divs are changed?

I have a jQuery code, which when a div i displayed the condition is true `$('#divID').css('display') == 'block'` is true  the background color should be changed but it's not working!.

jsfiddle: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/egzontina/x6py8kqu/10/)
My HTML code:

```
<body>
<br/><br/><br/>
<div id="ad1" style="display:block;" > Div content 1</div><br/>
<div id="ad2" style="display:none;"  > Div content 2</div><br/>
<div id="ad3" style="display:none;"  > Div content 3</div><br/>
<div id="ad4" style="display:none;"  > Div content 4</div><br/>
<br/><br/><br/>
<button id='button1'> click 1</button>
<button id='button2'> click 2</button>
<button id='button3'> click 3</button>
<button id='button4'> click 4</button>
</body>
```

and jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    if($('#ad1').css('display') == 'block'){
        $("body").css('background-color', '#ebb614');
    } 
    if($('#ad2').css('display') == 'block'){
        $("body").css('background-color', '#acb7a8');
    } 
    if($('#ad3').css('display') == 'block'){
        $("body").css('background-color', '#4f795b');
    } 
    if($('#ad4').css('display') == 'block'){
        $("body").css('background-color', '#7f7a6e');
    } 

    $('#button1').on('click', function () {
        $('#ad1').show();
        $('#ad2 ,#ad3 , #ad4').hide();
    });
    $('#button2').on('click', function () {
        $('#ad2').show();
        $('#ad1 ,#ad3 , #ad4').hide();
    });
    $('#button3').on('click', function () {
       $('#ad3').show();
        $('#ad2 ,#ad1 , #ad4').hide();
    });
    $('#button4').on('click', function () {
        $('#ad4').show();
        $('#ad2 ,#ad3 , #ad1').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hint: `$('#left-info1').is(':visible')` is a more traditional way of determining if that element is visible

Comment: @Jamiec i tried that but that doesn't fix my problem.. :/

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/o3mej4hj/1/). If this is what you need then I'll add my answer?

Comment: you are not changing background on click event? Which is missing?

Comment: I need  to check which div is displayed and based on that I want to change the body background  not on click event.  anyway thanks @DeepakBiswal

Comment: Yes men. In the button clicked event you are hiding some div and just showing one. So that way you are 100% sure which one is in display. Why to check which visible again. It does not make any sense.

Comment: For the very first time if you want to bydefault set some color then you can apply that logic.

Comment: Sorry, wasnt clear - my last comment was not how to fix this issue, it was just a better way of checking the visibility of an element

Comment: why you use 2 id attribute on the div ?

Comment: `$('#ad1').show();` `$('#ad2 ,#ad3 , #ad4').hide();`: This 2 lines of codes told you which is visiable. Do you want to check that again?

Comment: Because I have some other buttons next/prev that move into divs, and if I change color on button click when I use those buttons the color stay the same for all divs!!

Comment: @Mayank i edited my question, that mistake i did only on jsfiddle!

Comment: I'm not seeing those #left-infoX elements. As far as i see you should be testing for #adX elements not #left-infoX. $("#ad1").css("display")=='block'

Comment: Also, your conditionals will only be executed once, right when document ready is fired and they will not be checked again. I would put the tests inside a function and call it on every click button. Also would do it using classes, not ID's and get the background color from an attribute of the DIV

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira i edited my question, that mistake i did only on jsfiddle!

Comment: "*For that i want to make an independent function that will check when divs are changed?*" You answered your question right there. Put it in a function. Call it when they click and when the page loads.

Comment: I just added a solution in here so you can check it out. I'm using only one event to handle all code and also using classes to make it more simple. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33039489/835753

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira where is that solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*For that i want to make an independent function that will check when
>   divs are changed?*" You answered your question right there.

You answered your question right there. Put it in a function. Call it when they click and when the page loads.

In your code, you only set the background color on load. You need to run the check every time you change the visibility of the tabs. So put that code inside of a method and trigger it when the button is clicked or just put the line that sets the BG color in the click methods.

OR

You can simplify the code by using data attributes and simple selectors to select the other elements. No need for huge if else blocks with repeated code.

```js
$("button[data-id]").on("click", function(){
  var btnClicked = $(this).addClass("active");  //The button that was clicked
  btnClicked.siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
  $("body").css("background-color", btnClicked.data("color"));  //read the data attribute and set color
  $(".data.active").removeClass("active");  //remove the class from element that was already selected
  $(btnClicked.data("id")).addClass("active");  //add the active class so content shows up
});
$("#button1").click();  //Activate the first tab

$("button.page").on("click", function(){  
  var dir = $(this).data("dir"),
      btnTabs = $("button[data-id]"),
      activeBtn = btnTabs.filter(".active"),
      nextBtn;
  if (dir=="1") {
      nextBtn = activeBtn.next();
      if (nextBtn.length===0) {
        nextBtn = btnTabs.first();
      }
  } else {
      nextBtn = activeBtn.prev();
      if (nextBtn.length===0) {
        nextBtn = btnTabs.last();
      }    
  }
  nextBtn.click();  
});
```

```css
.data { display :none; }
.data.active { display : block; }

button.active { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ad1" class="data" id="left-info1"> Div content 1</div><br/>
<div id="ad2" class="data" id="left-info2"> Div content 2</div><br/>
<div id="ad3" class="data" id="left-info3"> Div content 3</div><br/>
<div id="ad4" class="data" id="left-info4"> Div content 4</div><br/>
<br/><br/><br/>
<div>
    <button id='button1' data-id="#ad1" data-color="#ebb614"> click 1</button>
    <button id='button2' data-id="#ad2" data-color="#acb7a8"> click 2</button>
    <button id='button3' data-id="#ad3" data-color="#4f795b"> click 3</button>
    <button id='button4' data-id="#ad4" data-color="#7f7a6e "> click 4</button>
</div>
<hr/>
<button class="next page" data-dir="-1">Prev</button>
<button class="next page" data-dir="1">Next</button>
```

Comment: I have some other buttons next/prev that move into divs, and if I change color on button click when I use those buttons the color stay the same for all divs!! For that I want to make an independent function that will check when divs are changed?!

Comment: So add in the functionality...Find the "next" button and click it.

Comment: Added next/prev logic just to show you it is possible.

Comment: that's great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Please try with the below code snippet or [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x6py8kqu/11/).

**Method 1:**

```
<body> 
<br />
<br />
<div id="ad1" style="display: block;">Div content 1</div>
<br />
<div id="ad2" style="display: none;">Div content 2</div>
<br />
<div id="ad3" style="display: none;">Div content 3</div>
<br />
<div id="ad4" style="display: none;">Div content 4</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<button id='button1'>click 1</button>
<button id='button2'>click 2</button>
<button id='button3'>click 3</button>
<button id='button4'>click 4</button>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#button1').on('click', function () {
            $('#ad1').show();
            $('#ad2 ,#ad3 , #ad4').hide();
            test(1);
        });
        $('#button2').on('click', function () {
            $('#ad2').show();
            $('#ad1 ,#ad3 , #ad4').hide();
            test(2);
        });
        $('#button3').on('click', function () {
            $('#ad3').show();
            $('#ad2 ,#ad1 , #ad4').hide();
            test(3);
        });
        $('#button4').on('click', function () {
            $('#ad4').show();
            $('#ad2 ,#ad3 , #ad1').hide();
            test(4);
        });
    });

    function test(id) {

        if (id == 1) {
            $("body").css('background-color', '#ebb614');
        }
        if (id == 2) {
            $("body").css('background-color', '#acb7a8');
        }
        if (id == 3) {
            $("body").css('background-color', '#4f795b');
        }
        if (id == 4) {
            $("body").css('background-color', '#7f7a6e');
        }
    }

</script>
<style>
    body {
        height: 5000px;
        background-color: #4e795b;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
</style>
</body>
```

**Method 2:**

```
<body>
    <div id="ad1" style="display: block;">Div content 1</div>
    <br />
    <div id="ad2" style="display: none;">Div content 2</div>
    <br />
    <div id="ad3" style="display: none;">Div content 3</div>
    <br />
    <div id="ad4" style="display: none;">Div content 4</div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <button id='button1'>click 1</button>
    <button id='button2'>click 2</button>
    <button id='button3'>click 3</button>
    <button id='button4'>click 4</button>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {


            $('#button1').on('click', function () {
                $('#ad1').show();
                $('#ad2 ,#ad3 , #ad4').hide();
                test();
            });
            $('#button2').on('click', function () {
                $('#ad2').show();
                $('#ad1 ,#ad3 , #ad4').hide();
                test();
            });
            $('#button3').on('click', function () {
                $('#ad3').show();
                $('#ad2 ,#ad1 , #ad4').hide();
                test();
            });
            $('#button4').on('click', function () {
                $('#ad4').show();
                $('#ad2 ,#ad3 , #ad1').hide();
                test();
            });
        });

        function test(id) {
            if ($('#ad1').css('display') == 'block') {
                $("body").css('background-color', '#ebb614');
            }
            if ($('#ad2').css('display') == 'block') {
                $("body").css('background-color', '#acb7a8');
            }
            if ($('#ad3').css('display') == 'block') {
                $("body").css('background-color', '#4f795b');
            }
            if ($('#ad4').css('display') == 'block') {
                $("body").css('background-color', '#7f7a6e');
            }
        }

    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            height: 5000px;
            background-color: #4e795b;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</body>
```

Below issue is exists in your given code:
1. you have implemented background color change logic in document.ready() but you have to recall this logic on every click event to change the background color.
2. you have added ID tag twice in your DIV.

Comment: This is not correct what I guess. In provided HTML there are 2 id properties which is not correct first. And then you are strictly hiding some element so why to check visible again. It will work but not perfect.

Comment: 1+ I think adding some explanation will be nice and result in more upvotes.

Comment: @DeepakBiswal  I have some other buttons next/prev that move into divs, and if I change color on button click when I use those buttons the color stay the same for all divs!! For that i want to make an independent function that will check when divs are changed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update background color on every button click because if condition will only check on document ready.

```
 $('#button1').on('click', function () {
        $('#ad1').show();
        $('#ad2 ,#ad3 , #ad4').hide();
        $("body").css('background-color', '#ebb614');
    });
    $('#button2').on('click', function () {
        $('#ad2').show();
        $('#ad1 ,#ad3 , #ad4').hide();
         $("body").css('background-color', '#acb7a8');
    });
    $('#button3').on('click', function () {
       $('#ad3').show();
        $('#ad2 ,#ad1 , #ad4').hide();
        $("body").css('background-color', '#4f795b');
    });
    $('#button4').on('click', function () {
        $('#ad4').show();
        $('#ad2 ,#ad3 , #ad1').hide();
        $("body").css('background-color', '#7f7a6e');
    });
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6py8kqu/7/)

Answer (score 0):

So I'm using a class to handle then buttons and also the divs instead. Also using attributes to have the backgorund colors and they are defined inside each div that have `background-changer` class.
It's a simple solution and also uses on single event to handle all this.

UPDATE:

> Added the Next/Prev Feature once  saw you requested it on the other answer. Keeping the simple code.
>   No using single event. Now its also using `document.ready` to start application

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/5x9jgbf9/2/)

```
<div id="ad1" class="background-changer active" data-background-color="#f00"  > Div content 1</div><br/>
<div id="ad2" class="background-changer" data-background-color="#0f0" > Div content 2</div><br/>
<div id="ad3" class="background-changer" data-background-color="#00f" > Div content 3</div><br/>
<div id="ad4" class="background-changer" data-background-color="#444" > Div content 4</div><br/>

<button id='button1' class="show-div-button" data-div-id="ad1"> click 1</button>
<button id='button2' class="show-div-button" data-div-id="ad2"> click 2</button>
<button id='button3' class="show-div-button" data-div-id="ad3"> click 3</button>
<button id='button4' class="show-div-button" data-div-id="ad4"> click 4</button>

<button class='show-div-button prev' data-div-id="">Prev</button>
<button class='show-div-button next' data-div-id="">Next</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    activateDiv($(".background-changer.active").attr("id"));
})
$(document).on("click",".show-div-button",function(){
    activateDiv(this.getAttribute("data-div-id"));
})
function activateDiv(id){
    $bgchangerarray = $(".background-changer");
    id = id =='' ? $bgchangerarray[0].id : id; 
    var $bgchanger = $("#"+id);
    $bgchangerarray.hide().removeClass("active");
    $bgchanger.show().addClass("active");;
    var count = $bgchangerarray.size()-1, 
        index = $bgchanger.index('.background-changer'), 
        next = index==count ? 0 : index+1,
        prev = index==0 ? count : index-1;
    $(".show-div-button.prev").attr("data-div-id",$bgchangerarray[prev].id)
    $(".show-div-button.next").attr("data-div-id",$bgchangerarray[next].id)
    $("body").css("background-color",$bgchanger.attr("data-background-color")); 
}   
</script>
```

Comment: I added the prev/next feature since i saw you requested in the other answer. yet keeping it simple | SAP Run Simple!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/o3mej4hj/1/).

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $('#button1').on('click', function () {
        $('#ad1').show();
        $('#ad2 ,#ad3 , #ad4').hide();
        $("body").css('background-color', '#ebb614');
    });
    $('#button2').on('click', function () {
        $('#ad2').show();
        $('#ad1 ,#ad3 , #ad4').hide();
        $("body").css('background-color', '#acb7a8');
    });
    $('#button3').on('click', function () {
       $('#ad3').show();
        $('#ad2 ,#ad1 , #ad4').hide();
        $("body").css('background-color', '#4f795b');
    });
    $('#button4').on('click', function () {
        $('#ad4').show();
        $('#ad2 ,#ad3 , #ad1').hide();
        $("body").css('background-color', '#7f7a6e');
    });
});
```

**PROBLEM:** In your code you are not changing the background on button click event. You just simply checking it in first load.